# Creating a coupon Product A + Product B and get 10% OFF

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, offers

I want to create a coupon.

The idea is Product A + Product B and get 10% OFF.

How to create this I tried some Ideas but, that didn't worked.

Here

Product Variant A.1, A.2, A.3 
Product Variant B.1, B.2, B.3 
Product Variant C.1, C.2, C.3

+
Product Variant D.1, D.2

What I want is that If someone chose B.2 + D.1 he gets 10% OFF
and so on. So, the important part is that 1 product from A,B,C and 1 from D.

Answer (score 0):

create shopping cart price rule with following condition

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the question again. I've modified it

Comment: Product Variant A,B,C,D is any atttribute?? if yes than create shopping rule using that attribute